# Why is my created file blank?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm having trouble storing data minus the header into a new file. I don't understand Python enough to debug.

Ultimately, I'd like to extract data from each file and store into one main csv file rather than opening each file individually, while copying and pasting everything into the main csv file I would like.

My code is as follows:

```
       import csv, os

# os.makedirs() command will create a folder titled in green or in apostrophies
os.makedirs('HeaderRemoved', exist_ok=True)

# Loop through every file in the current working directory.
for csvFilename in os.listdir('directory'):
    if not csvFilename.endswith('.csv'):
        continue #skips non-csv files
    print('Removing header from ' + csvFilename + '...')

    ### Read the CSV file in (skipping first Row)###

csvRows = []
csvFileObj = open(csvFilename)
readerObj = csv.reader(csvFileObj)
for row in readerObj:
    if readerObj.line_num == 1:
        continue # skips first row
    csvRows.append(row)
print (csvRows) #----------->Check to see if it has anything stored in array
csvFileObj.close()

    #Todo: Write out the CSV file
csvFileObj = open(os.path.join('HeaderRemoved', 'directory/mainfile.csv'), 'w',
                  newline='')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFileObj)
for row in csvRows:
    csvWriter.writerow(row)
csvFileObj.close()
```

The csv files that are being "scanned" or "read" have text and numbers. I do not know if this might be preventing the script from properly "reading" and storing the data into the csvRow array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from you reusing the same variable when you loop over your file names. See the documentation for `listdir`, it returns a list of filenames. Then your `newfile` isn't really pointing to the file anymore, but 
to a string filename from the directory. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir

```
with open(scancsvFile, 'w') as newfile:
    array = []
    #for row in scancsvFile
    for newfile in os.listdir('directory'): # <---- you're reassigning the variable newfile here
        if newfile.line_num == 1:
            continue
        array.append(lines)
newfile.close()
```